# compare column of file1 data with column of file2 data and save the output of file file in a different file

Tags: unix

I have two files .
**file1 data as -**

```
en_4156 A 282.97 1.44 i 1.00
en_4156 A 284.41 0.27 know 0.99
en_4156 A 291.41 1.32 i 1.00
en_4156 A 292.73 0.00 know 1.00
en_4156 A 292.73 1.38 i 1.00
en_4156 A 294.14 1.62 know 1.00
en_4156 A 296.09 2.64 what 0.55
en_4156 A 299.22 2.58 oh 1.00
en_4156 A 301.80 1.83 yeah 1.00
en_4156 A 303.91 0.84 well 0.95
en_4156 A 304.75 0.06 i'm 1.00
en_4156 A 304.84 0.00 going 0.95
en_4156 A 304.84 0.00 to 0.95
en_4156 A 304.84 0.48 have 1.00
en_4156 A 305.35 0.18 mine 0.98
```

**and file2 data as-**

```
en_4156 A en_4156_A 301.85 302.48 <O,en,F,en-F> OH YEAH
en_4156 A en_4156_A 304.71 306.72 <O,en,F,en-F> WELL I AM GOING TO HAVE MINE IN TWO MORE CLASSES
en_4156 A en_4156_A 307.63 311.16 <O,en,F,en-F> NO I AM NOT WELL THEN I HAVE TO TAKE MY EXAMS MY ORALS BUT
en_4156 A en_4156_A 313.34 315.37 <O,en,F,en-F> THAT IS KIND OF WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO
en_4156 A en_4156_A 316.83 319.20 <O,en,F,en-F> I MIGHT EVEN WANT TO GO ON AND GET MY P H D
en_4156 A en_4156_A 321.55 322.16 <O,en,F,en-F> IT IS JUST THAT
en_4156 A en_4156_A 323.05 327.38 <O,en,F,en-F> I DO NOT KNOW IT IS SO COMFORTABLE WHERE I AM AND AND IF I
en_4156 A en_4156_A 332.73 335.05 <O,en,F,en-F> LEAKY LISTEN I FLEW IN A FOUR SEATER PLANE
en_4156 A en_4156_A 335.79 338.72 <O,en,F,en-F> I WENT TO THE LAKE OF THE OZARKS (TW-) ON FOURTH OF JULY WEEKEND
en_4156 A en_4156_A 339.05 342.51 <O,en,F,en-F> I MET THIS GUY HE IS A TOTAL YAHOO BUT LET ME TELL YOU
en_4156 A en_4156_A 342.82 345.20 <O,en,F,en-F> I THERE WAS SOMETHING ABOUT HIM HE IS IN HIS FORTIES
```

my query is - **I need to compare the File1's column3 data with column4 data of File2 and save the file1 data in a file .**

can anyone write the script for this using awk.

Comment: Explain "compare the File1's column3 data with column4 data of File2" !

Comment: means that column3 data of file1 are 282.97,284.41....301.80 and so on and column4 data of file2 are 301.85 ,304.71 and so on.
if these two columns are matched then save the ouput of file1 in a new file.
like this-
en_4156 A 301.80 1.83 yeah 1.00

Comment: `can anyone write the script for this using awk.` Which payment option do you prefer? As your input seems to be already sorted, you can easily achieve it with `join`, which is exactly designed for that kind of task.